# Getting value of the ID "name" always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, user-input

When I retrieve the value of the ID "name" it always returns undefined. I used `document.getElementById("name").value;` but it was still showing an undefined error.

```js
const value = document.getElementById("name").value;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<input type =text" id="name">
```

Comment: `name` is not `id`

Comment: I don’t see that your input has an id with a value of “name”. Also you getElementById syntax is incorrect.

Comment: I converted your code into a live demo and it runs without errors (although since there is no value, it logs an empty string). "showing undefined ereor" is *very* vague through, you should quote the exact error message.

Comment: See also [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```html
<!-- ... -->

<input id="some_id" type="text" />

<!-- ... -->

<script>
  let el = document.getElementById('some_id');
  let value = el.value;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, they did. You can see that in the question.

Answer (score -3):

Give it an `id` to query by `ID`:

```
<input type =text" id="name">
```

then retrieve it by

```
document.getElementById("name").value
```

Comment: Your code appears to be identical to the code in the question. You didn't even fix the rogue `"` (which has no effect on the code running successfully).

Comment: He just editted it

Comment: He got it undefined because he queried the value right when he declared it, when the input is empty

Comment: An empty string is neither undefined nor an error.

Comment: That's what he got!

Comment: The OP **said** they got an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element is probably a duplicate but the OP hasn't provided a reproducable test case or quoted the actual error message they are getting.